# error in gpg keyserver command line option

Tags: gnupg

I need to find a key of a colleague on an internal keyserver.

Using `gpg --search-key name` results in:

```
gpg: error searching keyserver: Invalid argument
gpg: keyserver search failed: Invalid argument
```

The `.gnupg/gpg.conf` file contains:

```
keyserver: foo.bar
```

So I try manually:

```
$ gpg2 --keyserver foo.bar --search-keys name
gpg: no keyserver known (use option --keyserver)
gpg: keyserver search failed: No keyserver available
```

Ok, maybe the keyserver option goes after the search?

```
$ gpg2 --search-keys name --keyserver foo.bar
gpg: Note: '--keyserver' is not considered an option
gpg: no keyserver known (use option --keyserver)
gpg: keyserver search failed: No keyserver available
```

The manual page says the `--keyserver` option is deprecated, so I add this to the `.gnupg2/dirmngr.conf` file:

```
keyserver foo.bar
```

However the result does not change.

Am I missing something or is gpg's keyserver option broken?

Note: I've tried the keyserver both without schema and as hkp://foo.bar; the port is open as shown by this nmap scan:

```
Host is up (0.024s latency).

PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
11371/tcp open  http    SKS OpenPGP Key Server httpd ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `gpg --search-key name` and `gpg --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --search-key name` work for me on GnuPG v. 1.4.22 in cygwin.

Things that might be the cause for your problem:

- The keyserver is broken, try a different one
- The name contains weird symbols, try quoting it. Search for other names - do these searches work?